# When can two Cauchy transforms intersect?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, real-analysis, polynomials, sp.spectral-theory

Given two polynomials $p$ and $q$ over reals and being guaranteed that both have all roots real I want to know if there is any characterization of the solutions of the equation $\frac{p'}{p} = \frac{q'}{q}$.

- In particular I want to know if there is a known statement about when can the above equation  have a root which is $ > max\{maxroot(p),maxroot(q)\}$.
- And if a root of the above kind exists then can one say something about the value of $\frac{p'}{p}$ ( $= \frac{q'}{q}$) at that point?
- Also if a root of this equation exists which is $> max\{maxroot(p),maxroot(q)\}$ then can one somehow estimate where this root is by say knowing $p$ and $q$.

---

- If necessary feel free to assume that the roots of $p$ and $q$ are known exactly.
- If necessary assume that $p$ and $q$ are both monic polynomials of the same degree.

Answer (score 2):

If $p(z) = a \prod_{j=1}^d (z - r_j)$ and $q(z) = b \prod_{j=1}^e (z - s_j)$,
$r_1 \le r_2 \le \ldots \le r_d$, $s_1 \le s_2 \le \ldots \le s_e$,
then let $$ f(z) = \dfrac{p'}{p} - \dfrac{q'}{q} = \sum_{j=1}^d \dfrac{1}{z-r_j} - \sum_{j=1}^e \dfrac{1}{z-s_j} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{m_k}{z^{k+1}}$$
for $z > R = \max( r_d,  s_e)$, where $m_k = \sum_{j=1}^d r_j^k - \sum_{j=1}^e s_j^k$.  We may assume wlog the sets $\{r_j\}$ and $\{s_j\}$ are disjoint.

The sign of $f(z)$ as $z \to R+$ is positive if $r_d > s_e$, negative if $r_d < s_e$.  The sign as $z \to +\infty$ is that of the first nonzero coefficient $m_k$ (which must exist unless $d=e=0$).  A sufficient condition for the existence of a zero of $f$ in $(R,\infty)$ is that
these signs are different.

Moreover, by bounding the tail of the series we can 
place bounds on the location of any zeros.  Thus suppose the first nonzero coefficient is $m_k$.  We have
$|m_j| \le (d+e) M^j$ where
$M = \max(|r_1|,\ldots,|r_d|,|s_1|,\ldots,|s_e|)$, so that for $z > M$,
$$|f(z)| \ge \dfrac{|m_k|}{z^{k+1}} - \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty (d+e) \dfrac{M^j}{|z|^{j+1}} = \dfrac{|m_k|}{z^{k+1}} - (d+e) \dfrac{M^{k+1}}{|z|^{k+2}(1 - M/|z|)} $$

so any  zero must satisfy
$$ z \le M + \dfrac{(d+e) M^{k+1}}{|m_{k}|}$$

EDIT: $m_0 = d - e$, so that's the first nonzero coefficient if $d \ne e$.
If $d = e$, then at least one of $m_1, \ldots, m_d$ is nonzero.  To see this, consider the power-sums $M_i(X_1, \ldots, X_d) = \sum_{j=1}^d X_j^i$ for $ i=1\ldots d$ as symmetric polynomials in $X_1, \ldots, X_d$.  It is well-known that these form an algebraic basis for the symmetric polynomials in $X_1, \ldots, X_d$.  Let $Q(X_1,\ldots, X_d,y) = \prod_{j=1}^d (X_j - y)$.  This is nonzero if and only if $y \notin \{X_1, \ldots, X_d\}$, and its $k$'th derivative with respect to $y$ is nonzero if and only if at most $k$ of $X_1, \ldots, X_d$ are equal to $y$.  $Q(\cdot, \ldots, \cdot, y)$ and its derivatives with respect to $y$ are symmetric polynomials in $X_1, \ldots, X_d$, so they are determined by the power-sums $M_i(X_1, \ldots, X_d)$.
Thus the only way to have $m_j = M_j(r_1, \ldots, r_d) - M_j(s_1, \ldots, s_d) = 0$ for $j=1\ldots d$ is that $(r_1, \ldots, r_d)$ is a permutation of $(s_1, \ldots, s_d)$.

Comment: Thanks for the insights! (1) Finding this smallest $k$ for which $m_k \neq 0$ seems like an indefinite process right? Can this be done in a finite number of steps? (2) For my immediate purposes I can put in some further restrictions like $a=b=1$, $d=e$ and that the intervals $[ min(r_i,s_i),max(r_i,s_i)]$ are disjoint for all $i$ unless some repeated root of $p$ is common with $q$. Do these help refine anything?

Comment: And in the last inequality why are you thinking in terms of the modulus of $f(z)$? One can do the argument will the absolute values removed?  (but the hard part of the argument is about how does one estimate the value $k$?)

Comment: Also can you explain why is $sgn(f(max(r_d,s_e)^+)) = sgn(r_d-s_e)$ ?

Comment: If $d \ne e$, $m_0 \ne 0$.  Otherwise, I suspect the smallest $k$ can't be greater than $d$.

Comment: Why should $d$ be special? You mean if $d=e$ then $k < d=e$ ? Also can you explain why you claimed that $sgn(f([max(r_d,s_e) ]^+ ) ) = sgn(r_d - s_e)$

Comment: Consider the map $\Phi$ from subsets of $\mathbb R$ of cardinality $d$ to $\mathbb R^d$, taking $\{r_1, \ldots, r_d\}$ to the first $d$ moments $\left(\sum_i r_i^j,\ j=1\ldots d \right)$.  I suspect this map is one-to-one.

Comment: As for the sign thing, the point is that as $z \to p = \max(r_d, s_e)$ the dominant term in $f(z)$ is either $1/(z-r_d)$ or $-1/(z-s_e)$, depending on whether $p$ is $r_d$ or $s_e$.

Comment: Ah: it is one-to-one.  I'll edit that in to the answer.